# ThreadPoolExecutor from concurrent.futures module of Python for DRF appliction

Tags: django, multithreading, optimization, django-rest-framework, query-optimization

I have simple GET Project API, The following is my code approach
`
`class ProjectListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):`
`queryset = Project.objects.filter(is_deleted=False)`
`serializer_class = ProjectSerializer`
`def convert_to_json(self, state):`
`return State.convertProjectObjectToJSON(self, state=state)`

`def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):`

```
    try:
        objects = self.get_queryset()
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
            json_response = list(executor.map(self.convert_to_json, objects))
        response = response_body(status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=json_response)
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except Exception as e:
        response = response_body(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, data={str(e)})
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)`
```

This APIs taking 970ms for 200 Projects.
My question is Is this depends on the Threads so What should I need to deploy it on azure, do I have to make any changes regarding server configs or something else?